# SharePoint Form Print Preview Differnt from actual Hard Copy

Tags: infopath, form, printing, forms-library

I am experiencing a problem where the actual print out of a Form from SharePoint is different from the preview. We have three multiple selection list boxes that are populated from an external data source, in this case a SharePoint list.
When we run the print preview all checkboxes are displayed, including checked and unchecked boxes.
However the actual hard copy, only prints the checkboxes which are check and omits the unchecked boxes.
I have read there is some poor printer support for InfoPath. Has any experienced similar problems?